# XmlSearch() function in CF18 not returning expected result?

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing, cfml, coldfusion-2016

Guys I am working on CF18 server and facing issue XmlSearch function.
My XML looks like below

[image]

I am trying to search Polygon nodes here. I have tried in multiple ways but it returns empty array. I'm not sure what is wrong with my way.

```
<cfdump var="#isXML(parsedXML)#">    // return YES

<cfset selectedElements = XmlSearch(parsedXML,'/MultiSurface/surfaceMembers/Polygon')>
<cfdump var="#selectedElements#">  //Empty Array

<cfdump var="#XmlSearch(parsedXML, '//MultiSurface')#">   //Empty Array
<cfdump var="#XmlSearch(parsedXML, 'surfaceMembers')#">   //Empty Array
<cfdump var="#XmlSearch(parsedXML, '//surfaceMembers')#"> //Empty Array
```

Anyone can help me correcting this code.

Updated :

XML Data

```
<MultiSurface xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <surfaceMembers>
    <Polygon>
      <exterior>
        <LinearRing>
          <posList>41.710227999483223 -82.835759999441933 41.708971 -82.835118 41.708650999999996 -82.834508 41.708527 -82.833728999999991 41.708445 -82.833073 41.708635 -82.831451 41.709134 -82.830407 41.709300999999996 -82.829388999999992 41.709134 -82.828593 41.707156999999995 -82.823673 41.706951 -82.822746999999993 41.707038999999995 -82.819758 41.707347999999996 -82.816135 41.707451999999996 -82.81589799999999 41.707314 -82.815269 41.707381999999996 -82.814407 41.707215999999995 -82.813154 41.707225 -82.812176 41.707676 -82.811157999999992 41.707851999999995 -82.810531 41.707871 -82.810153 41.706157999999995 -82.807203 41.706325000248334 -82.806863999719781 41.706559999999996 -82.806877 41.708146 -82.808756 41.708321999513188 -82.808861000175852 41.708498 -82.808678 41.708772000261668 -82.808638998629959 41.709143999999995 -82.808874 41.709770999999996 -82.809592 41.713989999999995 -82.811667 41.715095999999996 -82.811771 41.715654 -82.811954 41.717280998996912 -82.811921999770249 41.717876 -82.811745 41.718444 -82.811236 41.719589000580818 -82.810518001459911 41.720625999999996 -82.810518 41.721547 -82.811039999999991 41.722273 -82.811616 41.723093 -82.812624 41.723257 -82.813013 41.72368 -82.813966999999991 41.72416 -82.816347999999991 41.724427999999996 -82.81888 41.724503 -82.819583999999992 41.724548999999996 -82.820409 41.724433999999995 -82.820866999999993 41.724183 -82.821569 41.723656999999996 -82.822729 41.723451 -82.823706 41.722809999999996 -82.82571999999999 41.722352 -82.8263 41.720065 -82.82746 41.719756 -82.82750999999999 41.718761 -82.82767299999999 41.718075 -82.827947999999992 41.71732 -82.828955 41.716885 -82.830603 41.716634 -82.831 41.716083999999995 -82.832037 41.71565 -82.832709 41.715168999209283 -82.832954000410936 41.714346 -82.832892 41.713637 -82.832403 41.713248 -82.83164 41.713043 -82.831516999999991 41.712699000512259 -82.831517000881448 41.711922 -82.831914 41.711258 -82.832585999999992 41.711234999999995 -82.833165999999991 41.711464 -82.834234 41.711487 -82.834752999999992 41.711304 -82.83515 41.710823 -82.835577 41.710227999483223 -82.835759999441933</posList>
        </LinearRing>
      </exterior>
    </Polygon>
    <Polygon>
      <exterior>
        <LinearRing>
          <posList>41.645933999690683 -82.8439370003459 41.645477 -82.84390599999999 41.644403 -82.841771999999992 41.644289 -82.841315 41.643856 -82.840857 41.643603999999996 -82.840278 41.64349 -82.838814 41.643215999999995 -82.838267 41.642172000740175 -82.836885999277143 41.640907 -82.837259 41.640541 -82.837319999999991 41.639419 -82.837869 41.63804700056199 -82.838111000738351 41.637269000336538 -82.838019000665952 41.636582999999995 -82.838324 41.635805 -82.838842 41.634843 -82.84003 41.634110999623005 -82.840425999186834 41.633241999999996 -82.840243 41.632075999508686 -82.8402420010428 41.631411 -82.840668 41.630610999999995 -82.841064 41.629466999381826 -82.841977999392441 41.629402999999996 -82.841985 41.628322999999995 -82.84209899999999 41.628139999999995 -82.841673 41.628163 -82.84149 41.628803999999995 -82.838472 41.628948 -82.837279 41.629124999999995 -82.83582 41.629194 -82.835209999999989 41.629331 -82.834662 41.630018 -82.833289999999991 41.630092999999995 -82.833169 41.63091 -82.831858 41.631436 -82.831291999999991 41.632099 -82.830578 41.633015 -82.828474 41.633700999999995 -82.827011 41.636148999999996 -82.824998999999991 41.636972 -82.824084 41.637955999999996 -82.82353599999999 41.638573 -82.822469 41.638912 -82.821754 41.639185999999995 -82.821191 41.639742 -82.820054 41.639831 -82.819876999999991 41.640701 -82.81939 41.641227 -82.818840999999992 41.64131 -82.818488 41.641448 -82.817906999999991 41.641501 -82.817681999999991 41.641776 -82.817011999999991 41.642348 -82.816707 41.642942 -82.816188 41.643696999999996 -82.813749 41.643800999999996 -82.81361 41.644086 -82.813231 41.644194 -82.813154 41.644771999999996 -82.812743 41.645846999999996 -82.812499 41.645939 -82.812407999999991 41.646945000808664 -82.812254999658307 41.647044 -82.812255 41.647746 -82.812255 41.648683 -82.81277399999999 41.649530000044223 -82.813048000376909 41.650376 -82.81292599999999 41.651039 -82.812591 41.651109999999996 -82.812513 41.651690999791015 -82.812117000166708 41.651903 -82.812176999999991 41.652083999999995 -82.812237 41.652144 -82.812388 41.652235 -82.812598999999992 41.652536000535513 -82.812599000948822 41.652716999999996 -82.812449 41.652747999999995 -82.811966 41.652843 -82.811838 41.653155999999996 -82.811425 41.654264999999995 -82.80975 41.655001999999996 -82.808263 41.655018999999996 -82.807935 41.655041 -82.80753 41.653749 -82.8053 41.653555 -82.803533 41.653600999999995 -82.803136999999992 41.653852 -82.802741 41.654401 -82.802556 41.654554 -82.802526 41.655179 -82.802404 41.655795999999995 -82.801855 41.656459 -82.800482 41.6571 -82.79972 41.657213999999996 -82.798957 41.657649 -82.798256 41.658197 -82.797493 41.659065999999996 -82.796821999999992 41.659945 -82.796421 41.660475 -82.796179 41.660804 -82.79602899999999 41.661283999999995 -82.795602 41.661296 -82.795583999999991 41.661992999999995 -82.794534 41.662496 -82.794198 41.663959999999996 -82.793802 41.664010999999995 -82.793751 41.664494999999995 -82.793266 41.6646920002521 -82.793069000805616 41.665262999999996 -82.793832 41.665870999999996 -82.795236 41.665949999999995 -82.795418 41.665973 -82.79633299999999 41.665607 -82.797216999999989 41.665461 -82.797754 41.665426 -82.797888 41.665236 -82.799258999999992 41.665248 -82.800202 41.664899 -82.801543 41.664428 -82.802121 41.664049999999996 -82.802821 41.664054 -82.803156 41.664415 -82.80465 41.664414 -82.805056999999991 41.66437 -82.805281 41.663405999999995 -82.806575 41.661682 -82.808587 41.659428 -82.824731 41.659524 -82.824821 41.659729999999996 -82.825521999999992 41.659684 -82.826285 41.659248999999996 -82.827474 41.658448 -82.829090999999991 41.658014 -82.830158 41.657899 -82.830799 41.657486999999996 -82.83336 41.657121 -82.834092 41.656389 -82.835129 41.653209 -82.837353999999991 41.652454 -82.83787199999999 41.65112 -82.839201 41.650281 -82.840036 41.649741 -82.840801 41.649549 -82.841073 41.648908 -82.841468999999989 41.648405 -82.841956 41.647766999999995 -82.84281399999999 41.647583999999995 -82.84319099999999 41.647149 -82.843649 41.646843 -82.843791 41.645933999690683 -82.8439370003459</posList>
        </LinearRing>
      </exterior>
    </Polygon>
    <Polygon>
      <exterior>
        <LinearRing>
          <posList>41.681655000723282 -82.8568309989808 41.681222 -82.8566 41.680854 -82.856403 41.68042 -82.855944999999991 41.680237 -82.855335 41.680169 -82.854388 41.680077999999995 -82.853442 41.679735 -82.852801 41.679232 -82.852313 41.678568999999996 -82.852069 41.677623 -82.851647 41.67754 -82.85161 41.676786 -82.849261 41.676809 -82.848529 41.676901 -82.848224 41.677267 -82.847338999999991 41.677656 -82.845413 41.677748 -82.84496 41.6787540002745 -82.84419800078183 41.678878 -82.844242 41.679097 -82.84432 41.679348999999995 -82.844839 41.679463 -82.845663 41.679623 -82.846913 41.680194 -82.84804299999999 41.680354 -82.848774999999989 41.680582 -82.851094 41.680718999999996 -82.851672999999991 41.681084 -82.853596 41.681861 -82.854817 41.681884 -82.856495 41.681655000723282 -82.8568309989808</posList>
        </LinearRing>
      </exterior>
    </Polygon>
  </surfaceMembers>
</MultiSurface>
```

Comment: Could you please post your xml data / structure if possible ?

Comment: @Kannan.P image is attached, Updated as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a wildcard for the namespace, i.e. `*:`

```
<cfdump var="#XmlSearch(parsedXML, '//*:Polygon')#">
```

... or

```
<cfdump var="#XmlSearch(parsedXML, '//*:MultiSurface/*:surfaceMembers/*:Polygon')#">
```

**Explanation:**

I'm presuming you're just the consumer of the xml and don't have the ability to alter it. The issue here is that the parent element contains a namespace declaration, i.e.

```
 <MultiSurface xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
```

However, the current search expression is designed for an element *without* one, i.e.

```
 <MultiSurface>
```

The declared namespace applies to the MultiSurface element, and its descendants. So it must be referenced in any search expressions to identify those elements. Usually namespace declarations include a "prefix": `xmlns:prefix="http://example.com/widget"`. The prefix is then used as a kind of shorthand when referencing elements, i.e. `prefix:ElementName`. In this case, there is no prefix, and the elements end up in a sort of unnamed space. So your search expressions must reference it by other means, such as

1. wildcards

   ```
   xmlSearch(parsedXML, "//*:MultiSurface")
   ```
2. [local-name()](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-local-name)

   ```
   xmlSearch(parsedXML, "/*[local-name()='MultiSurface']")
   ```
3. [namespace-uri()](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-namespace-uri)

   ```
   xmlSearch(parsedXML, "/*[local-name()='MultiSurface' 
               and namespace-uri() = 'http://www.opengis.net/gml']")
   ```

Each method has pros and cons. Method #1 and #2 are suitable for simple schemas and find matching elements in *any* namespace. For more complex schemas, having the same element(s) defined in multiple namespaces, method #3 is required to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Great @Ageax its perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I like using XMLParse because it gets me back to using ColdFusion structs and arrays very quickly. My code does not return an array. You many need to add code to deal with Polygon as single item or as an array.

```
 ...
    </LinearRing>
  </exterior>
</Polygon>   </surfaceMembers> </MultiSurface>

</cfsavecontent>


<cfdump var="#isXML(parsedXML)#">    // return YES

<cfset dataXML = XMLParse(parsedxml)>

<cfdump var="#dataXML.MultiSurface.surfaceMembers.Polygon#">
```

See: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=f4a9d905-110c-4a24-9102-e3812f17fe9b/4902bb97-63b6-4b91-b067-8990b8826819/6b3c45ca-ef2b-448a-abb9-4543ed17f392.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Your question is why your search is returning nothing. The answer is that your XML specifies a namespace (xmlns), whereas your search fails to specify a namespace.

You say you need help to correct the code. So here it is:

```
<cfxml variable="parsedXML" >
<n:MultiSurface xmlns:n="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <n:surfaceMembers>
    <n:Polygon>
      <n:exterior>
        <n:LinearRing>
          <n:posList>41.710227999483223 etc.</n:posList>
        </n:LinearRing>
      </n:exterior>
    </n:Polygon>
    <n:Polygon>
      <n:exterior>
        <n:LinearRing>
          <n:posList>41.645933999690683 etc.</n:posList>
        </n:LinearRing>
      </n:exterior>
    </n:Polygon>
    <n:Polygon>
      <n:exterior>
        <n:LinearRing>
          <n:posList>41.681655000723282 etc.</n:posList>
        </n:LinearRing>
      </n:exterior>
    </n:Polygon>
  </n:surfaceMembers>
</n:MultiSurface>
</cfxml>
<cfset searchResult1=xmlSearch(parsedXML, "//n:MultiSurface")>
<cfset searchResult2=xmlSearch(parsedXML, "//n:surfaceMembers")>
<cfset selectedElements = XmlSearch(parsedXML,'/n:MultiSurface/n:surfaceMembers/n:Polygon')>

<cfdump var='#searchResult1#' label="n:MultiSurface">
<cfdump var='#searchResult2#' label="n:surfaceMembers">
<cfdump var='#selectedElements#' label="n:Polygon">
```